# Autoscaling Spark Cluster: How to repartition after scale-out/scale-in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, aws-auto-scaling

I'm new to AWS & Spark and have been tasked to autoscale Spark clusters on AWS EMR. So far, I can get the cluster to autoscale, however, the Spark clusters processing slows to a crawl on scaling-out/in. I believe I need to repartition after a scale-out/in event.

I have a few questions:

1. How can we issue a command on Spark cluster to repartition?
2. Do we have to login to the master node?
3. Can we execute the command remotely?
4. Can we automate repartitioning after an autoscaling event? Perhaps a lambda function that checks running nodes on slave instance group, then executes repartition?
5. There may be an auto repartition feature? If there is and it's enabled, our clusters are still processing very slowly.

This is happening on different clusters running different processing applications.

At the moment, the only way we can scale-out/in is to start another cluster with different node count and gracefully shutdown the previous cluster, and it'll work fine. Would love ideas on how we can resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Repartition of what ? Here you’re experiencing the shuffle and idle or intermediate tasks that does stale or keeps trying to replicate, is my assumption. Your autoscaling would suffer and would more consider managed scaling, more controlled. Autoscaling is better on glue but didn’t saw it working good with simple emr cluster and especially if is streaming tasks or multiple file processing, works better if are core and node based.

Comment: @n1tk Repartition slave nodes (when slave node count increases in a master/slave setup). EMR managed scaling doesn't allow us to use custom metrics, there are no other built in metric that correlates on the amount of messages on queue for streaming tasks (kafka). So we're stuck with autoscaling.